# Fold DataFrame by joining string values from n adjacent rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to make my dataframe denser, so I've decided to join the string values of adjacent rows by a space. The fold size would be a parameter **fold_size**. To ilustrate:

```
# fold_size = 2
0
1
2
3
```

becomes:

```
0 1
2 3
```

I've written the code below, which works. But I wonder - can somebody come up with a more elegant way? After all, I've been using Pandas for a total of one day.

```
import pandas as pd

fold_size = 5
dic = { 'n': range(31), 'text': [str(n) for n in range(31)] }
df = pd.DataFrame(dic)

drop_ids = []
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if i % fold_size != 0:
        drop_ids.append(i)
        continue

    texts = []
    for j in range(fold_size):
        if i+j < len(df):
            texts.append(df.at[i+j, 'text'])
    df.at[i, 'text'] = ' '.join(texts)

df = df.drop(drop_ids).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a floor division of `df['n']` with `fold_size` and groupby with `agg` with `n` as `first` and `text` as `''.join`

```
df.groupby(df['n']//fold_size).agg({"n":"first","text":''.join}).reset_index(drop=True)
```

---

```
    n            text
0   0       0 1 2 3 4
1   5       5 6 7 8 9
2  10  10 11 12 13 14
3  15  15 16 17 18 19
4  20  20 21 22 23 24
5  25  25 26 27 28 29
6  30              30
```

Comment: Is the "first" some special key?

Comment: @OndrejSotolar `first` is an aggregation type which picks the first element in a group. Check this: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I think I understand it now.